# GetHostAddress not working when running ps1 files but works in powershell

Tags: powershell

i am trying to run the following command to get the IP of a hostname, the host is a virtual machine.

```
[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("virtualservername")
```

running this in powershell console i get the address fine, however when i run it by calling the command from a ps1 file. i get the error "No such host is known"

Comment: Is that the exact line you are using? As in the the virtualservername is the name provided as a string and not a variable?

Comment: Is this the only line in the ps1 file?

Comment: As others noted, the problem is most likely in something that you are not showing. If this is the *exact* line you are running on the same machine, you should be getting the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are directly calling `[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("hostname")` instead of assigning it to a variable, then try enclosing it inside a $() construct like this and try.

`$([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("hostname"))`